# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type

Tags: typescript

I don''t know how can i solve this...

```
// sessionTime: ["2021-05-27 00:00:00", "2021-05-28 00:00:00"]
const { sessionTime, routingTime, ...params } = parseQueryString(history.location.search)

if (sessionTime != null) {
  const sessionStartTime = sessionTime[0];     // <= type error occur this point
  ...
}
```

> [Error]
> *TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'string | number | boolean | (string | number | boolean)[]'.*

how can i solve this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error says that the type of `sessionTime` is:

```
string | number | boolean | (string | number | boolean)[]
```

That means that it might be many things. It could be an array as you seem to expect, or it could just be a `string | number | boolean`.

So you need to be sure it's an array before you treat it like one. You can do that by a test:

```
if (Array.isArray(sessionTime)) {
  // sessionTime is an array here
  console.log(sessionTime[0])
} else {
  // sessionTime is not an array here
  console.log(sessionTime)
}
```

[Working example on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mka0EtUAVfAWxAC5sMZ8UBzeAH3hQFdSAjEGZ+TpEgggoKPgApMtBn3ZcefAUJEoAlAG0AugCht+AGbxJuAsTIIAhAF5WbCBFXwA3tviJUmbCcIoAyhlgMEnJ4Gxw8H2CQdQAGTQBuNySAemT4AB4bDABPAAcEHhgkXiQwMDZeDAALfDR4XKQ6DG0AX10DI3DTFCj4a1t7eAAyIfgAQRgYKGyAOlqJqezjCLNyVUcXN2R0LC6ff0DesO9V6LjEpPhU1iR4HPz4QuLWoA)